# Two view controllers with table views inside scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How should I implement the table view- data source architecture for my following scenario:

- two view controllers each of one contains its own table view.
- table view cells are the same
- different data source (one should show names, the other one cities)
- view controllers are inside a horizontal scrollview
- data can be transferred from table1 to table2

My problem is I don't know what is the best way to represent the table views.

- Should I have one view controller with one table view and different data source ?
- two view controllers with two table views ?

Anyone has a good solution for me?
 I tried many solution, but my problem always is that I don't have a way to transfer data from one to another, because I cannot access the data source or when using protocols the delegate was nil.

Comment: What is your viewcontroller structure? Does one viewcontroller push another one using say, a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely have only one Tableview and one view controller (if possible) with 2 different datasources. One of the cardinal rules of programming is to never repeat yourself.

Say you 2 viewcontrollers A and B. 
A and B will both be instances of the same ViewController Class e.g. A = SomeViewController() and B = SomeViewController(). In the viewDidLoad, you can specify which datasource to use.

If you're having problems transferring data from Viewcontroller A to Viewcontroller B, you can create a public methods on SomeViewController class which will add objects to the datasource (e.g. addCityToDatasource:)

Then for example if you want a city from B to A, in **viewController B you call A.addCityToDataSource("Tokyo")** which will add the city to A's datasource

Comment: I still don't know how the transfer data should work. So I am creating this 2 VC and added them to scroll view, from another VC. So the I will create 2 instances: nameVC and citiesVC but both they use same view controller. So inside the view controller I dont have the 2 instances created...Its kinda confusing with me to udnerstand how all of things should work. Can you give an example if its not too much to ask ?

Comment: Sure no problem. Can you tell me a bit more about your use case?

Comment: It's ok, I kinda understand what you said and managed to fix it. Thanks.